# Read inbox of a user using "Google client library"

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to read inbox of a user using `Google client library`?

I am following this https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client, but can't find how to read inbox?

Comment: You mean their Gmail inbox?   If so, it [looks like it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/), yes.

Comment: Yes Gmail inbox. Please share the code

Comment: This [API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) should be of helpful to you.

Comment: It worked :) Thanks :)

Comment: Please share a demo iOS app